# Call Log-Likelihood in Statsmodels RegressionResults?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, regression, statsmodels

After running OLS with Statsmodels, I'm interested in the Log-Likelihood for comparing the fit of different models. I'm able to obtain the Log-Likelihood through the `res.summary()` function, but since I'm not interested in all available results in this summary, I would like to only call the Log-Likelihood.

I consulted the [documentation of RegressionResults](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html), but this gives me no answer. Can anybody tell me whether it is possible to obtain the Log-Likelihood result on its own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below. It gives the same Log-Likelihood in summary on its own.

```
print(res.llf)
```